# Using OpenGL GLEW within Unity

Tags: opengl, unity

**Edit:-**

How do I implement [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) (or OpenGL extension libraries) within Unity?

**Original Question:-**

I've recently been looking into some really nice features of OpenGL 3.2 that I want to take advantage of in the development of a tech demo. One example being Geometry Shaders and Tessellation: now I know that OSX 10.8 already implements OpenGL 3.2 but not all of the functionality has been exposed, that is where [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) comes in.

GLEW is a C/C++ extension... I have very limited C/C++ knowledge, would anyone be able to run through (in layman's terms) how to get GLEW working along side my C# Unity project.

Comment: Nothing in your question refers to unity except the headline and tag. Are you trying to combine unity and glew somehow?

Comment: This is all very fuzzy. Are you programming in C++? For OSX? Also, "how to get started" questions are not allowed here (check the [faq]), so you'll need to rephrase this title to turn it to a real, answerable, question.

Comment: You don't need GLEW (or any extension library) on MacOSX. Apple's OpenGL implementation already exports all the symbols.

Comment: Sorry, was terribly worded I've edited the question.  @ccxvii Do you think it's more a case of Unity not exposing this functionality in that case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unity is a higher level rendering engine which doesn't necessarily even use OpenGL for its rendering. (The default on Windows is DirectX, as far as I know.) But even if it did, extensions aren't usually things you can just 'switch on' and have it affect the rest of the system - the system usually has to be built in such a way as to make use of the extensions. So really you need to check which features Unity supports, without reference to OpenGL specifically.

Comment: Answers my question perfectly. Guess I might have to build my own engine